# extract phrase between single quotes regex and python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I want to extract from text phrases which are usually between single quotation

```
def extract_phrase(s):
    list = []
    pattern = re.compile("(?<=')[^']+(?=')")
    for value in pattern.findall(s):
        list.append(value)
    return list
```

```
print(extract_phrase("I can't Sleep and 'black lives matter'"))
['t Sleep and ', 'black lives matter']
```

as you can see the code return 2 strings, which is not good because I want only  the 'black lives matter' to return.

to fix it I tried to put \b at the start and in the end of the regex expression but i did not recieve anything when i made that change.

so how can i change the regex statement so i will get all strings from text that start with ' and end with '.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your single quotes are all balanced and unescaped then you may use this regex:

```
\B'.*?'(?!\w)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L6YOLX/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\B`: Asserts position where `\b` does not match
- `'` matches the character `'`
- `.*?`: Matches 0 or more of any character
- `(?!\w)`: Negative lookahead to assert that next character is not a word character

Comment: but now for example if i have  'black lives matter can't sleep' then it will return 'black lives matter can'.. instead of the entire string which is inside the single quotation mark. i need the quotion mark to be the first char and the string finishes when there is another quotion mark following by a whitespace (not tab or newline)